# Play swf files in C#

Tags: c#, flash

I add 'ShockwaveFlashObject' in toolbox and drag it on form and write below code but nothing happen why?

```
axShockwaveFlash1.Movie=Application.StartupPath+"\flash.swf";
        axShockwaveFlash1.Play();
```

and

```
axShockwaveFlash1.LoadMovie(0, Application.StartupPath + "\flash.swf");
        axShockwaveFlash1.Play();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because of escape character;

```
string path = Application.StartupPath+"\flash.swf";
```

path is actually equal to `C:\Users\username\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\bin\Debuglash.swf`
as you see `...\Debug + \f` has converted to `Debug`

to avoid escaping characters use `@`

```
string path = Application.StartupPath+@"\flash.swf";
```

now path is equal to `C:\Users\username\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\bin\Debug\flash.swf`

prolly that's what you want to get.

Comment: Nah, \f wasn't converted to Debug, \f is a largely invisible element and was just dropped. =)

Comment: @J. Steen you are right. what I was trying to say is `\Debug + \f` converts to  `Debug` or to  whatever the `StartupPath` will be there. thanks for pointing it, will edit the answer